# ActiveRecord simple query crashing server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a simple query that for some reason is hanging, causing heroku to hit max memory, and crashing the server.  I have never seen this behavior before so I am looking for suggestions on what might be causing this:

```
@city = params[:city] ? City.find(params[:city]) : City.first
SELECT "cities".* FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
```

Simple, but for some reason in all environments (dev, staging, and prod) it causes that weird behavior.

Connecting to sqlite db in dev, amazon rds mysql in stag and prod. (sqlite3 gem, mysql2 gem, ruby 2.0.0, rails 4.0.0)

Comment: When I took a look at this it just looked like typical Railsy magic to make the proper SQL query. It all looks correct to me so I'd be curious about your amazon rds and sqlite connection in dev. Try running sql console and seeing if you can get simple queries to execute

Comment: That's simply where it hangs in the logs.  Running the same query in console is fine.  The log stopping there is likely a red-herring, I guess.